# Accessing the Shadow DOM elements in Cypress

Tags: css, dom, cypress, shadow, shadow-dom

Cypress has provided [Shadow DOM](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/experiments.html#Shadow-DOM) support in the 4.8.0 release version. Yet somehow, I found it difficult to fetch the Shadow Elements using `.Shadow()` cypress commands.

Instead, I followed & installed additional cypress plug-in for implementation, where we can fetch shadow element with default cypress `cy.get()` command.
Reference: https://github.com/abramenal/cypress-shadow-dom#installation

Let's understand how to implement.

**Pre-requisites:**

1. Install: `npm install --save-dev cypress-shadow-dom`
2. Save: `import 'cypress-shadow-dom';`  (in command.js file)
3. Save: `"experimentalShadowDomSupport": true`, (in cypress.json file)

**Cypress Script to retrieve "value" from Shadow Element:**
Here am trying to fetch the Shadow element with the Parent id css selector referring to its value. And storing it in a variable 'text'.

```
cy.get('#id')                             //targeting the parent of Shadow
  .invoke('val')                         //Invoking the value of shadow
  .then((text) => {                   //get the text from shadow element, 
                  cy.log(text)          //so storing the text in variable
                  })                         //this logs the text in the Shadow element
```

**Cypress Script to input "value" into Shadow Element:**

If you are trying to input the value into shadow element:

```
cy.get('#id')  
  .invoke('val','input text in shadow element')   //invoking shadow element refering its value & the input new value
```

**Regarding the detailed implementation of the script with examples:**
**You can go through my blog:**
https://sahithigundu.blogspot.com/2020/09/how-to-access-shadow-dom-elements-in.html

Hope this helps.

Thanks,
Sahithi G
gsahithi.cse@gmail.com

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a question rather someone posting about how they implemented something. This is more suitable for a blog post.

Comment: Next time, instead you should "share knowledge Q&A style", which is done as follows: 1. ask a real question. 2. answer your own question. Your post should have been an answer to "how to access shadow dom elements in cypress?"

Comment: This isn't a question.